# Play Framework Scala: Is it possible to get null-able in key value pair like name:None?

Tags: scala, playframework

This might be a novice question, I really apologies for that but I wasn't able to find it any where. Code and output mentioned.

`Using Play Framework 2.3.9 (Scala)`

`// controller`

```
object Products extends Controller {
    def list = Action {
        Ok(Json.obj("products" -> Product.all))
    }
}
```

`// Model`

```
case class Product(id: Long, name: Option[String])

object  Product {

    implicit val format: Format[Product] = Json.format[Product]

    def all = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
        SQL("SELECT *   FROM    Products;").apply().map { row =>
            Product(
                id = row[Long]("id"),
                name = row[Option[String]]("name")
            )
        }.toList
    }
}
```

`output generated:`

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
    }, {
       "id": 2
    }]
}
```

`output wanted:`

```
{
    "products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
    }, {
       "id": 2,
       "name": null
    }]
}
```

Comment: `{ "name": None}` is invalid JSON. `{ "name": "None"}` is Valid and so is `{ "name": null}`

Comment: @RhysBradbury thanks, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of json value are you after for None? Do you mean a string "None", or the json null value `null`? At any rate, the formats line:

```
implicit val format: Format[Product] = Json.format[Product]
```

creates an automatic json formatter for you, but you can write your own to output the json in any custom format, e.g.:

```
implicit val productWrites = new Writes[Product] {
  def writes(product:Product) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> product.id,
    "name" -> product.name
    )
}
```

which will produce a value null (JsNull), i.e. `"name" : null`. for a product like Product(1,None). The following:

```
implicit val productWrites = new Writes[Product] {
  def writes(product:Product) = Json.obj(
    "id" -> product.id,
    "name" -> JsString(product.name.getOrElse("None"))
    )
}
```

would produce a json string value for name, i.e `"name":"None"`. More info available from the [relevant page on the play website](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson).

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is an implementation of `Writes[Product]` like so;

```
object Product {

  implicit val writes = new Writes[Product] {

    def writes(p: Product): JsValue = Json.obj(
      "id" -> p.id,
      "name" -> p.name // will output null and not None (as in your question)
    )

  }

}
```